# How do I get Kohana to call a specific controller?

Tags: kohana, controllers

My routing is set up like this:

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'static',
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```

so that typing in:

> http://localhost/et/testkohana4/

calls `action_index` on `Controller_Static` as it should.

However, when I type in:

> http://localhost/et/testkohana4/test

I expect it to say "**cannot find Controller_Test**" but instead, Kohana misses it and I get a message from Apache that says "**The requested URL /testkohana4/index.php/test was not found on this server.**"

Even when I put in a file under the `controller` directory called `test.php` with the class `Controller_Test` in it, I still get the page-not-found error.

**How can I get Kohana to call a specific controller when I type its name in the URL?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: The correct solution as provided in this answers comments was to change the .htaccess RewriteBase value to

```
RewriteBase /et/testkohana4/
```

---

```
(<controller>(<action>(/<id>)))
```

There's a mistake in your route. There is no forward slash at the beginning of `(<action> ...` That should be `(/<action> ...`

Those `<blocks>` are dynamic segments in the URL. So in this example:

```
http://localhost/et/testkohana4/test
```

Would result in this being called:

- **Controller**: et
- **Action**: testkohana4
- **ID**: test

That should work for you. Hope that helped.

Comment: even when I put the slash in, I still get the "Not found: The requested URL /testkohana4/index.php/news was not found on this server." I changed my `.htaccess` file back to `example.htaccess` but that didn't have any effect either. I had this working before, what could be causing Kohana not to see the text after my base URL as a controller name?

Comment: It sounds like an Apache rewrite problem. Am I writing in thinking your Kohana files in the sub-directory /et/testkohana4? If so, then you will need to modify the RewriteBase variable to "/et/testkohana4/"

Comment: thanks, that was it, I changed the line in `.htaccess` to `RewriteBase /et/testkohana4/` and it works.

Comment: I made a typo, but can no longer edit. I feel stupid. "Am I writing in thinking your". I'm aware of my mistake :P